# Actual domain names in phising posts?

Tags: phishing

I received a paypal scam email yesterday in the mail(*), which isn't particularly noteworthy, apart from the fact that not only was the sender paypal.com but the post was sent from mx4.slc.paypal.com.

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 173.0.84.229)
smtp.mailfrom=paypal.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
header.d=paypal.com;dmarc=pass action=none
header.from=paypal.com;compauth=pass reason=100
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of paypal.com designates
173.0.84.229 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
client-ip=173.0.84.229; helo=mx4.slc.paypal.com; pr=C
Received: from mx4.slc.paypal.com (173.0.84.229) by
BN7NAM10FT057.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.157.147) with Microsoft SMTP
Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
15.20.5438.12 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 19 Jul 2022 20:44:26 +0000
```

How is this possible?

(*) According to Paypal the first check with paypal emails is to see if the user's full name is stated at the start of the email, it wasn't just a generic "Dear paypal user"

Comment: Too few information. A Received header is nothing special, the attacker could create one itself before sending the mail. There would be more context needed (like the full header) to decide if this was the case here.

Comment: Assuming this is from the very beginning of the mail header: based on Authentication-Results DKIM, SPF and DMARC have passed, so that it looks actually from Paypal.

Comment: So the scammers have access to that mail server.

Comment: If this mail was really transmitted from paypals infrastructure and it is really a scam, I recommend that you forward the mail including all headers to phishing@paypal.com, so that they can analyze it further.

Comment: How are you sure that it was spam? Maybe it was legitimate?

Comment: Because the post didn't use my real name in the header, instead said "Dear Paypal user".  According to Paypal that is a give-a-way for a fake post.  Also Paypay said they would never send a post requiring an immediate response like the fake post did.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the little information provided, this header appears to be from a legitimate Paypal server. Most likely, this is a genuine e-mail sent by Paypal.

In case it is really a spam message, Paypal should be alerted about this, since one of their mail servers is the used in the sending of spam. Consider forwarding the e-mail to phishing@paypal.com, as indicated in the comments.